# Node/Webpack on Laravel is going Bonkers

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webkit, laravel-5.4

I have been compiling my project for many months now and it has never been an issue. I was coding for most of today with `npm run watch` on. Then suddenly it stop compiling CSS, watch was still running but CSS was not updating.

A commit to Bitbucket reveals the following:

public/mix-manifest.json

```
{
-  "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
-  "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
+  "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js"
}
```

The app.css has been removed?

public/js/app.js

```
 /******/   function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
 /******/
 /******/       // Check if module is in cache
-/******/       if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
+/******/       if(installedModules[moduleId])
 /******/           return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
-/******/       }
+/******/
 /******/       // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
 /******/       var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
 /******/           i: moduleId,
```

...

```
 /***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

 "use strict";
-Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
-/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {/* harmony import */ var         __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__components_passwordValidator__ = __webpack_require__(9);
+/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
+/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__components_passwordValidator__ = __webpack_require__(9);
 /* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__components_passwordShowHide__ = __webpack_require__(8);
 /* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__components_selectComponent__ = __webpack_require__(10);
 /* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__components_showHideComponent__ = __webpack_require__(11);
```

...

```
 /* 2 */
 /***/ (function(module, exports) {

-// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin
+throw new Error("Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/dashboard-details-2.jpg' in 'F:\\openvisa-webapp\\resources\\assets\\sass'\n    at factoryCallback (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\Compilation.js:260:39)\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:243:19\n    at onDoneResolving (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:59:20)\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:132:20\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:3799:9\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:360:16\n    at iteratorCallback (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:934:13)\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:844:16\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:3796:13\n    at apply (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:21:25)\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:56:12\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModuleFactory.js:124:22\n    at onResolved (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\Resolver.js:70:11)\n    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)\n    at afterInnerCallback (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\Resolver.js:138:10)\n    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)\n    at Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\tapable\\lib\\Tapable.js:181:46)\n    at innerCallback (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\Resolver.js:125:19)\n    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\tapable\\lib\\Tapable.js:283:15\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:38:4\n    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)\n    at afterInnerCallback (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\Resolver.js:138:10)\n    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)\n    at Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\tapable\\lib\\Tapable.js:181:46)\n    at innerCallback (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\Resolver.js:125:19)\n    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)\n    at F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\tapable\\lib\\Tapable.js:283:15\n    at innerCallback (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\Resolver.js:123:11)\n    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\\openvisa-webapp\\node_modules\\enhanced-resolve\\lib\\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)");

 /***/ }),
 /* 3 */
```

I've tried putting configuring the public/mix-manifest.json back to the way it was:

public/mix-manifest.json

```
{
"/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```

Run `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` and it will just remove the `"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"`

public/mix-manifest.json

```
{
-"/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
-"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
+"/js/app.js": "/js/app.js" 
}
```

The Node Error that I get after running `npm run dev` is:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"     "C:\\Users\\Cory\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\openvisa-webapp\npm-debug.log
```

Please note I don't get this error when running `npm run watch` it just doesn't compile CSS, this Error only comes up on `npm run dev`. But neitherless the error is still there on `watch`.

I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried `npm install`, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. This will happen if your CSS background images don't have a correct path.